# Nginx not setting Vary header via add_header directive in server block?

Tags: nginx, http-headers, gzip

I have

```
gzip_vary on;
```

I also have (inside a `server` section):

```
add_header Vary Origin;
```

Yet when I inspect headers sent, the Vary header only includes `Accept-Encoding`; if I remove the `gzip_vary on;` line then there is no `Vary` header emitted at all.

I'm on nginx 1.10.3, can anyone shed light?

Comment: Do you have any other `add_header` in locations which are defined later on? Make sure to account for the fact of how this directive is inherited: if you have a directive on the inner location, then any directive from outer is "lost".

Comment: I do not have any other `add_header` (at least not for "Vary"), although even if I did I would expect those to be added to the output, possibly by concatenation on a single header, as is documented - I think it's a standard that multiple headers of the same type are valid and may be treated the same as a concatenated one.

Comment: Note: While I'm still interested in this behaviour, my reason for needing this was that my CORS responses were being cached and therefore a cached response to one origin was being sent to another for which it is invalid. I solved that by ensuring the `$http_origin` variable was included in the cache key value.